# Simple sweet-exp statement not working

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying sweet-exp but following simple function is not working:

```
#lang sweet-exp racket 

(define (g x)
  {x * 1 + 2 - 3 / 4})   ; << ERROR IS POINTING HERE.

(g 5)
```

The error is in the define function g statement:

```
 nfx: unbound identifier in module in: nfx
```

I could not find an answer on http://docs.racket-lang.org/sweet/index.html

Where is the problem?

Comment: `#lang sweet-exp` doesn't support precedence. This is a very intentional design choice to make the syntax more general and flexible. So you'll have to write `{{{x * 1} + 2} - {3 / 4}}`.

Comment: To be fair to @mso, that error message is awful. Like, where did `nfx` even come from?